React transform data using reduce
I need to transform the following structure using React.
export const bodyRows = [
  {
    row: [{ cell: "Name" }, { cell: "Allan, Trent" }, { cell: "Smith, Nathan" }, { cell: "Howard, Greg" }],
  },
  {
    row: [{ cell: "Student ID" }, { cell: 332 }, { cell: 333 }, { cell: 334 }, { cell: 335 }, { cell: 356 }],
  },
  {
    row: [{ cell: "Studkey" }, { cell: "333-B" }, { cell: "334-B" }, { cell: "335-B" }, { cell: "336-B" }, { cell: "332-B" }],
  },
  {
    row: [{ cell: "Name" }, { cell: "Smith, Trent" }, { cell: "Ryan, Nathan" }, { cell: "Johnson, Greg" }],
  },
  {
    row: [{ cell: "Student ID" }, { cell: 232 }, { cell: 233 }, { cell: 234 }, { cell: 235 }, { cell: 256 }],
  },
  {
    row: [{ cell: "Studkey" }, { cell: "233-B" }, { cell: "234-B" }, { cell: "235-B" }, { cell: "236-B" }, { cell: "232-B" }],
  },
  {
    row: [{ cell: "Name" }, { cell: "Lewis, Trent" }, { cell: "Roberts, Nathan" }, { cell: "Roberts, Greg" }],
  },
  {
    row: [{ cell: "Student ID" }, { cell: 132 }, { cell: 133 }, { cell: 134 }, { cell: 135 }, { cell: 156 }],
  },
  {
    row: [{ cell: "Studkey" }, { cell: "133-B" }, { cell: "134-B" }, { cell: "135-B" }, { cell: "136-B" }, { cell: "132-B" }],
  },
];

I have the following and I can't get it working correctly. Could anyone please recommend how to solve this?
const bodyRows = studentHistory.map((students) => ({
    row: [{ cell: "Name" }, { cell: students.studentName }],
    row: [{ cell: "Student ID" }, { cell: students.studentId }],
    row: [{ cell: "Studkey" }, { cell: students.studentHistoryId }],
  }));

Output example:


Use reduce method instead

@RyWilli Is that works ?

@YuvarajM it works. Thank you so much!

I've updated my original post of the expected outcome. If there's multiple records, how can I achieve this?

Could you share the exact body structure to produce that output ?

@YuvarajM I've updated my original post with the body structure

@RyWilli I've updated my answer, If it's not the way you want just let me know with the input data.

Thank you for your response. Would that only work when there's 3 objects? How would it handle dynamic data?

If it was dynamic then we need some logic to filter items, It would be studentId range or something to separate data into multiple records.

For that you need to use Array.reduce method.


const studentHistory_1 = [
  {
    studentName: "Allan, Trent",
    studentId: 332,
    studentHistoryId: "333-B"
  },
  {
    studentName: "Allan-2",
    studentId: 331,
    studentHistoryId: "333-c"
  },
  {
    studentName: "Huge",
    studentId: 3321,
    studentHistoryId: "333-s"
  },
  {
    studentName: "Jackman",
    studentId: 3211,
    studentHistoryId: "333-g"
  }
];

const studentHistory_2 = [
  {
    studentName: "Allan, Trent",
    studentId: 232,
    studentHistoryId: "232-B"
  },
  {
    studentName: "Allan-2",
    studentId: 233,
    studentHistoryId: "233-c"
  },
  {
    studentName: "Huge",
    studentId: 234,
    studentHistoryId: "234-s"
  },
  {
    studentName: "Jackman",
    studentId: 235,
    studentHistoryId: "235-g"
  }
];

const studentHistory_3 = [
  {
    studentName: "Allan, Trent",
    studentId: 132,
    studentHistoryId: "132-B"
  },
  {
    studentName: "Allan-2",
    studentId: 133,
    studentHistoryId: "133-c"
  },
  {
    studentName: "Huge",
    studentId: 134,
    studentHistoryId: "134-s"
  },
  {
    studentName: "Jackman",
    studentId: 135,
    studentHistoryId: "135-g"
  }
];

const bodyRowsGenerate = studentHistory => {
  return studentHistory.reduce((body, student) => {
    const { studentId, studentName, studentHistoryId} = student;
    student.studentName && body[0].row.push({
      cell : studentName
    }); // For name row
    
     student.studentId && body[1].row.push({
      cell : studentId
    }); // For id row
    
     student.studentName && body[2].row.push({
      cell : studentHistoryId
    }); // For key row
    
    return body;
  },[
    {
      row: [{ cell: "Name" }]
    },
    {
      row: [{ cell: "Student ID" }]
    }, 
    {
      row: [{ cell: "Studkey" }]
    }
  ]);
}

const bodyRows = [
  ...bodyRowsGenerate(studentHistory_1),
  ...bodyRowsGenerate(studentHistory_2),
  ...bodyRowsGenerate(studentHistory_3),
];

console.dir(bodyRows)




I see you're trying to transform your data into a table, but I think there's a bit of confusion with your code:

You're overwriting the row property in your .map() function, so only the last row will show up. Were you trying to have multiple rows in the same object?

Also, could you clarify how you want the table structured? From the example image, it looks like you want the data to display horizontally with 'Name', 'Student ID', and 'Studkey' as the headers, but I just want to be sure I'm on the right track.


Once I have a bit more context, I'll try to help you out with the solution
